# Android SQLite - small I/O difficulty

Tags: android, database, sqlite, input

I have create a basic program to help learn SQLite & Android. The application has 2 activities in total:

Activity 1: User inputs both First and Last name, presses the submit button. On submit, this data will be added to the database, and activity #2 is called.

Activity 2: This activity simply takes the recent input from the database and displays it on screen.

The problem is, I am getting a NullPointer exception when running the code. I have added the relevant code for both activities, and my Database code in the hope someone can show me where I have been going wrong. Thanks for any help given.

Activity 1:

```
public class DBExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Declare the database object and open.
    MyDBManager db = new MyDBManager(this);
    db.open();

    // Take names from EditTexts and store in string.
    first_name  = fname.getText().toString();
    last_name   = lname.getText().toString();   
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // In the onclick method, add values to database, call next activity
    db.insertData(first_name, last_name);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Display.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Activity 2:

```
public class Display extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Cursor myCursor = db.getDetails();

    // Get relevant data from columns in cursor.
    username =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name")); 
    password =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name")); 

    // set textview values.
    fname.setText(first_name);
    lname.setText(last_name);    
}}
```

Database Code:

```
public class MyDBManager {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "firstname";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "lastname";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User_Information";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "User_name";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
                    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + 
                    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
                    "username text not null, " + 
                    "password text not null); "  ;

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public MyDBManager(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creates the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        // on triggered if the database version has increased. 
        // used if you want to change structure of column: eg add new column.
    }
} // end helper class



// Methods used to access and change data in DB:
public MyDBManager open() throws SQLException{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}   


public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}

public long insertData(String username, String password){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}


public Cursor getDetails(long rowId){
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_USERNAME,
                    KEY_PASSWORD},
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}}// End myDBManager Class.
```

EDIT: ADDED LOGCAT

> 02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.dbex/com.android.dbex.Display}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at com.android.dbex.Display.onCreate(Display.java:26)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
>   02-07 16:36:59.376: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     ... 11 more

Comment: When exactly are you getting the NullPointer exception, when you're running the app or when you're trying to go to Activity 2 ?

Comment: Yes when the next activity is called.

Comment: Please post your Logcat output and which lines it is referencing so we can actually see where you are getting the error instead of guessing.

Comment: LOGCAT added to original post

Answer (score 0):

You haven't instantiated your views in the second activity:

```
TextView fname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview1);
TextView lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview2);
 // set textview values.
    fname.setText(first_name);
    lname.setText(last_name);
```

Comment: Hi DuZi, thanks for the reply. As far as I'm aware, when the DB is opened once it stays in that state until closed. But I have tried your suggestion to no avail..

Comment: Oh, ok. So then the Log would be useful ;)

Comment: Hey Duzi, I had already declared the TextViews, but I did not think it relevant to include in the problem code. The error seems to be database related. Well spotted though.

Comment: Also, in your getDetails-Method you expect a long-parameter but aren't passing any argument in your 2nd activity

Comment: Ah, I had created two getDetails(), one excepting an arg and one without. I seem to have posted up between implementations. However, when providing an arg it does not work.

Comment: oh my... :) what about this:
you try to get a string via = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name"));
but in your DbManager you declared it as "firstname"

Comment: I have fixed this issue soon after posting, didnt realise it was posted here! :)